# How to change start and end date of DateListPlot with Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, date-and-time

Let's say I have a one dimension list `d` with length `L`. The $x$-axis in the plot starts from `{2013, 8, 28 + start}` and ends in `{2013, 8, 28 + end}`, and I want to change the `start` and `end` date with `Manipulate`.

So

```
d[[1]] (*--> 2013/8/28*)

d[[2]] (*--> 2013/8/29*)
```

So I think it would be:

```
Manipulate[
  DateListPlot[d, {{2013, 8, 28 + start}, {2013, 8, 28 + end}}],
  {{start, 0}, 0, L},
  {{end, L}, 0, L}
]
```

But when I plot it, it gives me an error when `a>3` because the day of the date is greater than `31` (I think).

How would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
L = 20; 
Manipulate[
 DateListPlot[Range@50, {DatePlus[{2013, 8, 28}, start], DatePlus[{2013, 8, 28}, end]}],
 {{start, 0}, 0, L},
 Item[Dynamic@DatePlus[{2013, 8, 28}, start], Alignment -> Left],
 {{end, L}, 0, L},
 Item[Dynamic@DatePlus[{2013, 8, 28}, end], Alignment -> Left]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

If you do not know the frequency of your data, or just want to be robust to it, there are two options. One is the standard `Take` or `Part` constructs. The other is `PlotRange`, which works fine for the horizontal axis of `DateListPlot`s.

```
fakedata = 
  Transpose@{DatePlus[{2001, 1}, {#, "Month"}] & /@ Range[0, 99], 
    Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]] - 2};

Manipulate[
 DateListPlot[fakedata, Joined -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{start, end}, Automatic}], 
 {start, AbsoluteTime@{2000, 12}, AbsoluteTime@{2004, 6}}, 
 {end, AbsoluteTime@{2005, 6}, AbsoluteTime@{2009}}]
```

[image]

You could change the outer bounds of the `Manipulate` ranges for `start` and `end` to reference the data if you wanted. Just be careful to make sure that `start` cannot be greater than `end`, or **Weird Stuff™** happens.

Comment: +1 I wonder whether the logo of **Weird Stuff**™ is a pentagon or an heptagon

Comment: @belisarius it changes randomly between the two, and nobody can understand why. It's weird. ;-)